# Return rows based on conditions across rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not sure if such a query is possible. I tried a few different queries, but none is returning the desired output. Here is the requirement:

I have 2 tables:

```
Header:

Id(PK)  Name
1       A
2       B
3       C

Detail:

Id(FK)  Name    Min     Max
1       X1      1       3
1       X2      5       5
1       X3      8       9
2       X1      11      11
2       X2      13      13
2       X3      15      18
3       X1      2       2
3       X2      1       6
3       X3      9       11
```

I need a query that given the following input:

```
@X1 = 2
@X2 = 5
@X3 = 9
```

Should output:

```
Id(PK)  Name
1       A
3       C
```

Since the provided values fall between the Min and Max in the Detail table.

Also, an input of 0 indicates no range, so for example:

```
@X1=0
@X2=0
@X3=16
```

Should output:

```
Id(PK)  Name
2       B
```

Even though @X1 and @X2 are 0 and do not fall between any range, 0 here means "everything is acceptable". Had @X3 also been 0, it would have outputted all: Header Id 1, 2 and 3, since all records fall within range.

I know I can do this using temp tables and stored procedure or even processing it in Java; but I was wondering if this was possible through direct SQL

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: Do all three values have to fall within the min and max for a given Id?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes, all three values have to fall between the range. Please look at the first example. I updated it to better reflect the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct d1.ID
from Detail d1
    inner join Detail d2 on d2.ID = d1.ID and @x2 = 0 or @x2 between d2.Min and d2.Max
    inner join Detail d3 on d3.ID = d1.ID and @x3 = 0 or @x3 between d3.Min and d3.Max
where @x1 = 0 or @x1 between d1.Min and d1.Max
```

You can wrap it to subquery and join to it to get other details from Header table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT h.Id,h.Name
  FROM Header h
     JOIN Details d
       ON h.id=d.id
   WHERE ((@x1 BETWEEN d.Min and d.Max)
         OR (@x2 BETWEEN d.Min and d.Max)
          OR (@x3 BETWEEN d.Min and d.Max))
```